# In a Ruby on Rails app, I'm trying to loop through an array within a hash within an array. Why am I getting "syntax error" message?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I have a Ruby on Rails application to enter results and create a league table for a football competition.

I'm trying to input some results by creating records in the database through heroku and I get error messages.

The application isn't perfectly designed: to enter the results, I have to create the fixtures and enter the score for each team. Then, independently I have to record each goal scorer, creating a record for each goal which is either associated with an existing player or requires me to firstly create a new player and then create the goal.

When I ran the code below heroku, I got this error:

syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end

Maybe I'm missing something simple about lopping through an array within a hash?

Thank you for any advice!

```
coalition = Team.find_by(name: "Coalition")
moscow_rebels = Team.find_by(name: "Moscow Rebels")
red_star = Team.find_by(name: "Red Star")
unsanctionables = Team.find_by(name: "The Unsanctionables")
cavalry = Team.find_by(name: "Cavalry")
galactics = Team.find_by(name: "The Galactics")
happy_sundays = Team.find_by(name: "Happy Sundays")
hardmen  = Team.find_by(name: "Hardmen")
international  = Team.find_by(name: "International")

evropa = Venue.find_by(name: "Evropa")

s28 = Season.find_by(number: 28)

start_time = DateTime.new(2020,9,6,11,0,0,'+03:00')


scheduled_matches_1 =
[
{team_1: cavalry, team_1_goals: 1, team_1_scorers: ["Minaev"], team_2_goals: 6, team_2_scorers: ["Kovalev", "Kovalev", "Kovalev", "Thomas", "Thomas", "Grivachev"], team_2: coalition, time: start_time, venue: evropa, season: s28},
{team_1: hardmen, team_1_goals: 4, team_1_scorers: ["Jones", "Jones", "Jones", "Fusi"], team_2_goals: 2, team_2_scorers: ["Kazamula", "Ario"], team_2: galactics, time: start_time + 1.hour, venue: evropa, season: s28},
{team_1: international, team_1_goals: 9, team_1_scorers: ["Kimonnen", "Kimonnen", "Kimonnen", "Burya", "Burya", "Zakharyaev", "Zakharyaev", "Lavruk", "Rihter"], team_2_goals: 0, team_2_scorers: [], team_2: happy_sundays, time: start_time+2.hours, venue: evropa, season: s28}
]

scheduled_matches.each do |match|
    new_fixture = Fixture.create(time: match[:time], venue: match[:venue], season: match[:season])
    tf1 = TeamFixture.create(team: match[:team_1], fixture: new_fixture)
    tf2 = TeamFixture.create(team: match[:team_2], fixture: new_fixture)
    ts1 = TeamScore.create(team_fixture: tf1, total_goals: match{:team_1_goals})
    ts2 = TeamScore.create(team_fixture: tf2, total_goals: match{:team_2_goals})
    match[:team_1_scorers].each do |scorer|
        if Player.exists?(team: tf1.team, last_name: scorer) 
            Goal.create(team_score: ts1, player: Player.find_by(last_name: scorer))
        else 
            new_player = Player.create(team: tf1.team, last_name: scorer) 
            Goal.create(team_score: ts1, player: new_player)
        end
    end
    match[:team_2_scorers].each do |scorer_2|
        if Player.exists?(team: tf2.team, last_name: scorer_2) 
            Goal.create(team_score: ts2, player: Player.find_by(last_name: scorer_2))
        else 
            new_player = Player.create(team: tf2.team, last_name: scorer_2) 
            Goal.create(team_score: ts2, player: new_player)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using braces when you meant to use brackets to access the hash. Below is one of the issues, but the same issue is in `ts2`.

```
  ts1 = TeamScore.create(team_fixture: tf1, total_goals: match{:team_1_goals})
```

should be **match[:team_1_goals]**

```
  ts1 = TeamScore.create(team_fixture: tf1, total_goals: match[:team_1_goals])
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have `scheduled_matches_1` at the top and `scheduled_matches.each do...` further down.

But the real issue here is that your variable names match the data content, rather than being used to *hold* the content. If a new team joins your league, you have to change the code. Next week, you are going to have to change the hard-coded date value. Your `scheduled_matches_1` data structure includes the active record objects returned by the first set of `Team.findByName()` calls. It would be easier to fetch these objects from the database inside your loops, and just hold the team name as a string in the hash.

There is some duplication too. Consider that each fixture has a home team and an away team. Each team has a name, and an array (possibly empty) of the players who scored. We don't need the number of goals; we can just count the number of players in the 'scorers' array. The other attributes, like the location and season belong to the fixture, not the team. So your hash might be better as

```
{
  "fixtures": [
    {
      "home": {
        "name": "Cavalry",
        "scorers": [
          "Minaev"
        ]
      },
      "away": {
        "name": "Coalition",
        "scorers": [
          "Kovalev",
          "Kovalev",
          "Kovalev",
          "Thomas",
          "Thomas",
          "Grivachev"
        ]
      },
      "venue": "Evropa",
      "season": "s28"
    }
  ]
}
```

because then you can create a reusable method to process each team. And maybe create a new method that returns the player (which it either finds or creates) which can be called by the loop that adds the goals.

Also, as it stands, I'm not sure the code can handle 'own goals', either. Perhaps something for a future iteration :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes - the database isn't very well designed. The goals and the scores are independent because it's designed for referees to input results and when I created it I didn't know to build it properly.